# Differential equation where derivative is polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = a_1 x + a_3 x^3 + a_5 x^5 + ...$

where only odd powers of $x$ are included. Can this be solved in general? If not, can it be solved if I only take a limited number of polynomials? (Say, only 1 and 3.)

I tried a solution along the lines of $x = a_1 e^{r_1t}+a_2 e^{r_2t^2} + a_r e^{r_3t^3} + ...$ but that didn't really pan out, as the non-first terms of the derivative of will then be exponentials, multiplied by some power of $t$, which won't be the case for any terms of $x^3, x^5, ...$

Similarly, a plain polynomial solution also doesn't work, because the derivative of $x^N$ is $Nx^{N-1}$, introducing even powers of $x$.

Comment: At any given finite truncation it can technically be solved but you need the roots of the right hand side in order to carry out the partial fraction expansion, and that's only available in closed form for arbitrary coefficients if you stop when the exponent is at most 9 (and it's only not incredibly awkward if you stop when the exponent is at most 5).

Comment: @Ian: I guess the 9 comes from the fact that, in $\sum a_i x^i=0$, you could divide by x once, and then replace y=x^2, leaving you with a 4th degree polynomial, which is still solvable, unlike a 5th degree? And if you had the roots, (easy if I stop at a power of 3), then what would the solution look like?

Comment: Separation gives a logarithm and (assuming $a_1,a_3$ have the same sign) an arctan, which is hard to solve for $x$.